# hyperlink styling

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I am trying to style hyperlinks: some must be white, and some others must be normal color.  Here is what I have:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/register.php" class="normal">Register</a>

a:link {
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
a:visited {
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:active {
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.normal a:hover{
    color:#00F;
}
.normal a:link{
    color:#00F;
}
.normal a:visited{
    color:#00F;
}
.normal a:active{
    color:#00F;
}
```

The normal links work fine.  But when I use the `class=normal`, the link is still white.  Why are the normal links taking precedence?

Comment: Try writing like <a class="normal" href="http://www.mysite.com/register.php">Register</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try define the class normal like this:

```
a.normal:hover
{
    color:#00F;
}
a.normal:link
{
    color:#00F;
}
a.normal:visited
{
    color:#00F;
}
a.normal:active
{
    color:#00F;
}
```